# Cannot start Redis service when I running on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error below. How can I make the service run again?

[image]

When I run **docker ps** below is the output:

[image]

Comment: docker-compose not able to found the network.

Comment: Usually `docker-compose up` and `docker ps` write out text output, not PNG files.  Can you replace the two screenshots with the actual output of these commands?  This question is also missing some key details like the `docker-compose.yml` file; providing a [mcve] would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened because you tried to bring up an environment where you had already bound the port elsewhere.

To fix...

Either

`docker-compose down` which will delete the containers + network.

OR

`docker ps -a` find the stuck container and then remove it with `docker rm -f CONTAINER_XX`